# Correct interpretation of exponential decay and decay factor

Tags: exponential-function

my question is about exponential **decay** and its factor.

English isn't my native language and therefore I'm not sure about the precise definition in my particular case.

I'm reading a specific paper and here it is described, not so well, an algorithm. The part I'm not sure about is as follow: I have a **x** variable of value **1e-7**, this algorithm has a loop and it is said that after every 10 iterations it is applied to **x** "**an exponential decay with decay factor 0.95**".

Do you think the correct interpretation would be to multiply the actual **x** value for **$e^{-0.95}$** at each step that the update is required? As wikipedia states, the $\lambda$ is called **constant** and not **factor**

Another option could be for me to multiply by **0.95** and not **$e^{-0.95}$**

I'm sorry if my question is dumb but I can't verify the answer with brute force and I think this is the best place to find the most accurate one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an exponential decay of $5\%$ after 10 steps then the equation is

$$e^{-\lambda x}=e^{-\lambda 10}=0.95\Rightarrow \lambda=\frac{-\ln(0.95)}{10}\approx 0.00512933$$

If we have an inital value of $5$ then after 10 steps we have $y(10)=5\cdot e^{-0.00512933\cdot 10}=4.75=5\cdot 0.95$

This is what we wanted. For a reference see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialDecay.html).

Here is a graph with the initial value $5$. You see that the decay is not linear.

[image]

Comment: I don't need to update it at each step **i**, but only when $i=11,22,33...$, therefore I would consider $x=1$ when $i=11$, $x=2$ when $i=22$ or simply $x=\frac{i}{11}$.

Comment: Have you mentioned that in your question?

Comment: Hum, I reported the exact same statement as in the paper and this is my interpretation of "after every 10 iterations it is applied to x "an exponential decay with decay factor 0.95""

Comment: You start at t=0 and then after ten steps ($t=10$) it is updated.

Comment: Yes, if I'm correct you are telling me that "to apply to **x** an exponential decay with decay factor 0.95" correspond to a simple $x=x*0.95$ to use only when the step is 11,21,31 (I was wrong when I said 11,22,33).. (or 10,20,30 if you start to count at 0)

Comment: The decay process itself is continuous. But at  the times $10t$ it is $I_0\cdot 0.95, I_0\cdot 0.95^2, I_0\cdot 0.95^3,...$ for $t=1,2,3$, where $I_0$ is the initial value.

Comment: I´ve added a graph. So it is **not linear** like $y=I_0*0.095*t$

Comment: Yeah sure, I used $x=x*0.95$ and that overwrites **x**, in other words it does exactly what you said. Got it that the process is continuous but inside the algorithm I have to consider the function as discrete because I use "steps" and not "time". Anyway thank you for your time and for clarifying my doubts

Comment: You can define x as integers. Then the values which are not integers don´t have to be regarded. You´re welcome.